# Echarts DataZoom make height bigger

Tags: echarts

Does anyone know how to set the height of the Data Zoom slider?

This page https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/12582 suggests it is possible .. there is a height option that seems to half work, but if you increase it, the slider height increases outside the chart area, so only a part of it is visible. I.e. need to be able to move the slider up too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dataZoom` option like:

```json
      dataZoom: [{
        type: 'slider',
        height: 70,
        bottom: 20
      }],
```

(and don't forget to shrink chart area)

```js
    const chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

    let base = +new Date(1968, 9, 3);
    let oneDay = 24 * 3600 * 1000;
    let date = [];
    let data = [Math.random() * 300];
    for (let i = 1; i < 20000; i++) {
      var now = new Date((base += oneDay));
      date.push([now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, now.getDate()].join('/'));
      data.push(Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20 + data[i - 1]));
    }

    option = {
      title: {
        left: 'center',
        text: 'Data Zoom Lab'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: date
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        boundaryGap: [0, '100%']
      },
      height: 200,
      dataZoom: [{
        type: 'slider',
        height: 70,
        start: 30,
        end: 40,
        bottom: 20
      }],
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Fake Data',
          type: 'line',
          symbol: 'none',
          sampling: 'lttb',
          itemStyle: {
            color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
          },
          areaStyle: {
            color: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
              {
                offset: 0,
                color: 'rgb(255, 158, 68)'
              },
              {
                offset: 1,
                color: 'rgb(255, 70, 131)'
              }
            ])
          },
          data: data
        }
      ]
    };

    chart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.2.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```